# Zoomable Widget with Fixed Position

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a zoomable widget while I'm using a widget with elements placed in a fixed way (with margin)

Here I have a BodyWidget fixed at a size of 340*560 that places body parts via margins :

```
return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Container(
      width: 340,
      height: 560,
      child: Stack(
        children: bodyParts.map((BodyPart d) => _bodyPart(d)).toList(),
      ),
    ));
```

My ZoomableWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

class ZoomableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double scale;

  const ZoomableWidget({Key key, this.scale = 1.0, this.child})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ZoomableWidgetState createState() => _ZoomableWidgetState();
}

class _ZoomableWidgetState extends State<ZoomableWidget> {
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    matrix.scale(widget.scale);
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
        setState(() {
          matrix = m;
        });
      },
      child: Transform(
        transform: matrix,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When my Widget can take up enough space, everything goes well I can zoom properly:

[image]     [image]

On the other hand, when I restrict the available size (I set a Row with 2 widgets at flex 1), the inner elements don't fit correctly, even if I set a scale of 0.5 for example (You can see hands and forearms not placed correctly) :

[image]

How can I make sure that my elements are placed correctly, and then the Zoomable is applied?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What about using OverflowBox instead?

```
return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: OverflowBox(
      maxWidth: 340.0,
      maxHeight: 560.0,
      child: Stack(
        children: bodyParts.map((BodyPart d) => _bodyPart(d)).toList(),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Thx for that ! I didn't know that widget and I Can manage it with this one!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zoom](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget) widget
Add to Imports

```
import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';
```

Then add this

```
return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Zoom(
      width: 340,
      height: 560,
      child: Stack(
        children: bodyParts.map((BodyPart d) => _bodyPart(d)).toList(),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still exist with this component